# Parsing a string, in a more specific way?

Tags: python, string, parsing, python-2.7, string-parsing

For a given input string `input = "abbbbdeeefffddddb"`, I want to parse it to

`result = ['a', 'b', 'bb', 'bd', 'd', 'e', 'ee', 'f', 'ff', 'dd', 'db']`

The logic behind this parsing is the following. If a substring is encountered for the first time, it is parsed away. In each subsequent occurrence of a substring it is concatinated with the following letter and then parsed away.

To illustrate:

1. Have we seen "a" (position 0) before? NO Parse it.
2. Have we seen "b" (position 1) before? NO Parse it.
3. Have we seen "b" (position 2) before? YES; Merge with the following letter
4. Have we seen "bb" (position 2 & 3) before? NO Parse it.
5. Have we seen "b" (position 4) before? YES Merge with the following letter
6. Have we seen "bd" (position 4 & 5) before? NO Parse it...

This continues till the end.

I tried to achieve this with the following code:

```
input = "abbbbdeeefffddddb"

comparator = []

def parse(string):
    for pointer in range(len(string)-1):
        if string[pointer] not in comparator:
            comparator.append(string[pointer])

        else:
            substring = string[pointer] + string[pointer+1]
            comparator.append(substring)

        print comparator 

parse(input)
```

This is the result: `['a', 'b', 'bb', 'bb', 'bd', 'd', 'e', 'ee', 'ef', 'f', 'ff', 'fd', 'dd', 'dd', 'dd', 'db']`

And it is wrong. I am missing a key piece here, but I don't know how to implement it, Maybe it requires some recursive function, or I should use `break` or `continue` somewhere.

Do not provide solution only for this given input. The input given here is just for the sake of example. Solution has to be general to apply to different inputs as well.

Here is the original algorithm, page 6: [paper](http://ravijainweb.com/pcs/locpred/locpred-cheng-jain.pdf)

Comment: Maybe you should keep track of the letters you have seen.

Comment: this is a job for regex if I've ever seen one..

Comment: @Marcin I am using the `comparator` list to add there the letters that I have already encountered. Is that what you mean? or smth else?

Comment: @WolfgangKuehne Yes, I know you're doing that, but clearly it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to forget skipping parsed letters from bigrams:

```
def parse(string):
    pointer = 0
    while pointer < len(string):
        if string[pointer] not in comparator:
            comparator.append(string[pointer])
        else:
            substring = string[pointer] + string[pointer+1]
            comparator.append(substring)
            pointer += 1
        pointer += 1
    print comparator
['a', 'b', 'bb', 'bd', 'e', 'ee', 'f', 'ff', 'd', 'dd', 'db']
```

or slightly rewritten

```
def parse(string):
    result = set()
    letters = iter(string)
    for letter in letters:
        if letter not in result:
            result.add(letter)
        else:
            substring = letter + letters.next()
            result.add(substring)
    return list(result)
# same set, different order
['a', 'bd', 'b', 'e', 'd', 'bb', 'f', 'ee', 'dd', 'db', 'ff']
```

Comment: Unfortunately `ef` and `fd` should not be part of the correct result. I have provided the expected result above. Please have a look. :)

Comment: next try :) is 5'td 'd' requiered. gonna give up, too sleepy :)

Comment: why the code does not work for a different input. For example if we have more `b`s that are given in the `input`. Lets say we have 6 `b`s instead of 4. At that case `bbb` has to be parsed as well, because we have already encountered `b` once; thats why it became  `bb`. Now the next letter to stick to that substring will be the last `b`, resulting in `bbb`

Comment: Adding 'bbb' is out of scope of your original question as it was stated. It seems to be your duty to provide relevant and extensive testcases.

Comment: sure, but algorithms are not designed to work for specific inputs. I gave that input just to exemplify. Yet, it is my mistake that I did not mention this earlier

Comment: yet your algorithm description is very vague for me, you'd better provide test cases instead of `The input given here is just for the sake of example`, which is meaningless.

Comment: maybe I have oversimplified stuff by trying to avoid extra confusion. If you are interested this is the algorithms that I am trying to implement [link](http://ravijainweb.com/pcs/locpred/locpred-cheng-jain.pdf) refer to page 6

Answer (score 2):

Is this about what you want?

```
$ cat single-seen-double
#!/usr/bin/python3

def single_seen_double(string):
    length = len(string)
    index = 0
    seen = set()
    while index < length:
        if string[index] in seen and index < length - 1:
            yield string[index:index+2]
            index += 2
        else:
            seen.add(string[index])
            yield string[index]
            index += 1

def main():
    print(list(single_seen_double("abbbbdeeefffddddb")))

main()

zareason-dstromberg:~/src/outside-questions/single-seen-double x86_64-pc-linux-gnu 5871 - above cmd done 2013 Tue Nov 05 01:48 PM

$ ./single-seen-double
['a', 'b', 'bb', 'bd', 'e', 'ee', 'f', 'ff', 'd', 'dd', 'db']
```

It doesn't give quite your sample output, but I'm wondering if this isn't what you were really looking for.  If it's not what you need, could you be more specific about what rule you need followed?

Comment: the order is not a problem. Your solution gives the expected result for this input, however if the input changes it does not work. Your solution always parses the string in form of double characters. This parsing that I am trying to accomplish is based on the LZ parsing algorithm given in the following paper: [link](http://ravijainweb.com/pcs/locpred/locpred-cheng-jain.pdf) page 6 provides the required information

Answer (score 0):

What is a problem in using set?

`set(comparator)`

if orders are not important.

Comment: using `set()` will remove the duplicates, but still `fd` and `ef` are not supposed to appear in the result. Yeah the order is not important btw.